# How do I find the correct python urllib2 splitted_page list index?

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I'm having trouble getting the contents within this splitted_page. All I want is the headline which reads `"Sian Blake partner ..."`

Here is my code. It seems to be printing way to much information than what I require

```
import urllib2

url="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-35412127"

request = urllib2.Request(url)

handle = urllib2.urlopen(request)

content = handle.read() 

splitted_page = content.split("<h1 class=\"story-body\">");

splitted_page = splitted_page[0].split("</h1>")

print splitted_page[0]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have problem because you use wrong class - it has to be `story-body__h1`

I prefer `requests` and `lxml` so I used them to create working example

```
import requests
import lxml, lxml.html

url="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-35412127"

r = requests.get(url)

html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)

print(html.cssselect('.story-body__h1')[0].text)
```

---

**EDIT:** now your code works too - you need `story-body__h1` and `[1]` in place of `[0]`

```
import urllib2

url="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-35412127"

request = urllib2.Request(url)

handle = urllib2.urlopen(request)

content = handle.read() 

splitted_page = content.split("<h1 class=\"story-body__h1\">");

splitted_page = splitted_page[1].split("</h1>") # [1] instead of [0]

print splitted_page[0]
```